# "404: not found" error on SolidJS project deployed to Vercel

Tags: vercel, solid-js, solid-start

I recently created a personal website using SolidJS, with server side rendering and typescript enabled. I attempted to deploy this site to Vercel, with the only change from the base Vercel settings being that I changed the Output Directory to 'dist'. However, after deploying the site I am getting a 404 error. You can find the uploaded site (and the error) [here](https://personal-website-ten-sooty.vercel.app/), and the github repo for my solidjs project [here](https://github.com/harryalbert/personal_website). I have also attached a screenshot of my Vercel Build & Development Settings. Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this issue? Thank you!
[image: Vercel Build & Development Settings]

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to change my vite config to plugins to
'''
plugins: [solid({adapter: vercel()})],
'''

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @Harry Alberts answer:

You'll need to `npm i solid-start-vercel` to install SolidJS ***Adapter for Vercel***

Then add:

```
import vercel from "solid-start-vercel";
```

to the *vite.config.ts* file along with this:

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        solid({ adapter: vercel({ edge: true }) })
    ],
});
```

I tried this `solid({ adapter: vercel() })` but got an error since the `vercel()` function expects an argument of type **SolidStartVercelOptions** which has these as keys:

```
{
  edge: boolean,
  includes: string | string[],
  excludes: string | string[],
  prerender: PrerenderFunctionConfig
}
```

And if you have the **vercel cli** installed, run this:

`vercel env add ENABLE_VC_BUILD`

and set the the value of ***ENABLE_VC_BUILD*** to **1**

Hope this is enough information for those needing it.

Reference:

[SolidJs Vercel Adapter Github](https://github.com/solidjs/solid-start/tree/cbafb3108b79533f6492719af74842df1c7fe26e/packages/start-vercel)

[SolidJS Github Issue About Vercel](https://github.com/solidjs/solid-start/issues/591)